# Bot can't connect to guilds

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to code a C# Discord Bot and it's just working fine so far. But since today it can't connect to any guilds. I'm 100% sure, I'm using the correct token and I've also authorized the bot to my own discord server, but it always throws this error:

> [   Error] Gateway: Error handling Dispatch (GUILD_AVAILABLE)

This is the code, I'm using to connect to guilds:

```
public async Task MainAsync()
{
    client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
    {
        LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose
    });
    commands = new CommandService();
    services = new ServiceCollection().BuildServiceProvider();

    await InstallCommands();

    await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
    await client.StartAsync();

    client.Log += Log;

    client.UserJoined += UserJoined;

    await Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What version of Discord.Net are you using? This is a known issue with 1.0.1 and has been fixed in later versions. See here: https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/issues/810#issuecomment-328253426

Comment: Oh wow, i've updated all nuget packages and now it is working again. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem. I'll post my response as the answer so that you can close this question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with 1.0.1 and has been fixed in later versions, so you'll need to update. See here: https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/issues/810#issuecomment-328253426.